# Use native query with Spring Projection Interface to select fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I want to know how can I populate these classes:

```
interface BaseDTO {

    Integer getId();

    String getNome();

    Boolean getAtivo();

    RegionalDTO getRegional();

    MunicipioDTO getMunicipio();
}

interface RegionalDTO {

    Integer getId();
}

interface MunicipioDTO {

    Integer getId();
}
```

And run this query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT " +
        "base.ID_BASE AS id, base.NOME AS nome, base.ATIVO AS ativo, " +
        "regional.ID_REGIONAL AS ID_REGIONAL, " +
        "municipio.ID_MUNICIPIO AS ID_MUNICIPIO " +
        "FROM TB_BASE base " +
        "LEFT JOIN TB_REGIONAL regional on base.ID_REGIONAL = regional.ID_REGIONAL " +
        "LEFT JOIN TB_MUNICIPIO municipio on base.ID_MUNICIPIO = municipio.ID_MUNICIPIO " +
        "ORDER BY base.ID_BASE", nativeQuery = true)
List<BaseDTO> getAll();
```

So I want to select the fields in the query, because later I will put more fields in theses DTO.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simplest way would be to use simple interface with only ids for `regional` and `municipio`. After calling `getAll` map this interface to appropriate class structure (where ids turn into dtos).

```java
List<RealDTO> result = repository.getAll().stream()
  .map(i -> new RealDTO(i))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I need to convert my DTOS, to class

```
@Value
public class BaseDTO {

    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    private MunicipioDTO municipio;
    private RegionalDTO regional;

    public BaseDTO(Integer id, String nome, Integer municipioId, Integer regionalId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.municipio = new MunicipioDTO(municipioId);
        this.regional = new RegionalDTO(regionalId);
    }
}


@Value
public class MunicipioDTO {    
    private Integer id;    
}

@Value
public class RegionalDTO {    
    private Integer id;    
}
```

So in my repository I did it

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.apivgosmobile.dto.model.BaseDTO(base.id, base.nome, municipio.id, regional.id)" +
        "FROM Base base " +
        "LEFT JOIN base.municipio municipio " +
        "LEFT JOIN base.regional regional " +
        "WHERE base.ativo = 1 " +
        "ORDER BY base.id ASC")
List<BaseDTO> getAll();
```